# "W/SystemWebViewClient﹕ URL blocked by whitelist" in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, whitelist

My application has in intermittent issue:
I already have a whitelist plugin added to the Cordova project. If I build it in my machine the URLs are accessed fine. However if my teammate builds the project from his machine I have this error:

```
    W/SystemWebViewClient﹕ URL blocked by whitelist: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXX&libraries=places
```

But not only from Google, also other domains the app accesses externally.

Cordova version is `5.0.0`. According to the [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/index.html): 
`Access to all domains, for example, google.com and developer.mozilla.org:`

```
<access origin="*" />
```

I already have it. Here's the config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.XXX.XXX" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>XXX</name>
    <description>
        XXX
    </description>
    <author email="XXX" href="">
        XXX
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />

    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
    <plugin name="DatabasePlugin" value="com.XXX.XXX.database.DatabasePlugin"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <platform name="android">
     </platform>
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Comment: Check your firewall settings.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 i installed the application in my phone using data. so it could not be the firewall...

Comment: you state, *"However if my teammate builds the project from his machine I have this error:"* What does your phone have to do with their failure?

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 i'm trying to figure out, it could not be the version because both of us has greater than `5.0.0` cordova version.

Comment: I'm going to try this ONE MORE time before I give up - because it appears you are have a problem with focus. MY RESPONSE was to check the firewall. This means your firewall AND your \*teammate's\* firewall.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm getting the same error and can't figure out why.

Answer (score -2):

You have two platform tags for android. Perhaps, one is being used by one computer and the other by the other :)

```html
<platform name="android">
</platform>
<platform name="android">
  <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
```